# Settings AngularJS Filter (such as date or currency) Programmatically from Variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In Angular, you can easily format variables using filters, such as these:

```
{{ myDate | date }}
{{ myMoney | currency }}
```

Is there any way to programmatically set the type of the filter so that it looked something like this?

```
// controller 
$scope.myFilter = 'date';

// view
{{ myVar | myFilter }}
```

Context: I'm returning tabular data from my server along with some meta information. I'd like to display things like dates, money, or numbers without having to hand-code the columns.

Here's a link to a very simple, and non-functional Plunker of this problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/SjYLKKUZcTjzRFhbsjK0

Comment: One question, three distinct working solutions.

Comment: @stewie : the wonder of stack overflow!

Comment: Yeah, it's great to get different approaches for when they will be useful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap your filters up into a 'table cell filter' or similar, and switch on a filter parameter - which could be controlled programmatically.

Here is a quick example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/1DGOC1gFZiFyGAQRCIhk?p=preview

**In your template:**

```
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="value in values">{{value | myfilter:myFilterType }}</li>
  </ul>
```

**The filter:**

```
app.filter('myfilter', function() {
    return function(input, type) {
    switch(type) {
        case 'uppercase':
          return input.toUpperCase();
        case 'lowercase':
          return input.toLowerCase();
        case 'date':
          return input.toString('dddd, MMMM ,yyyy');
        }  
    };
});
```

Note that if required, you could load other filters and apply them to the input inside that one, so that your code is clean and DRY.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply filters programmatically, but I don't think it's possible to do it that way.
If you're OK with defining filtered values inside the controller, then you might do it like this:

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {

  $scope.values = [new Date(-1), new Date()];

  $scope.myFilter = 'date';

  $scope.$watch('values', function(values){
    $scope.filteredValues = [];
    if(!angular.isArray(values)){
      return;
    }
    angular.forEach(values, function(value){
      $scope.filteredValues.push($filter($scope.myFilter)(value));
    });
  });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="value in filteredValues">{{value}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hXOeZvHjpHOulIhD7s2Y?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler alternative is to just call a function when you display the value. This way you can reuse the $filter service and also add your own logic. See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tPo7GXuHNKL5XX5eeNC6?p=preview).

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.values = ['Test #1', 'Test #2'];

  $scope.myFilter = 'uppercase';
  $scope.myFilterFn = function(value) {
    console.log(value);
    var filter = $filter($scope.myFilter);
    console.log(filter);
    return filter(value);
  };
});
```

Template:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>{{myFilter}}</p>
  <button ng-click="myFilter = 'uppercase';">Uppercase</button>
  <button ng-click="myFilter = 'lowercase';">Lowercase</button>
  <p>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="value in values">{{myFilterFn(value)}}</li>
    </ul>
  </p>
</body>
```